# I want to get data from grid when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

$("#wa30_05_roomList").kendoGrid({

```
         dataSource: wa30_05_roomDataSource,
         height: 550,
         autoBind: false,
         groupable: false,
         scrollable : true,
         sortable: true,
         selectable: 'row',
         change: fn_wa30_05_gridClick,
         columns: 
         [
             { title: "<span class='checkbox'><input id='wa30_05_allChk' type='checkbox'><label for='wa30_05_allChk'></label></span>"
             , width: 30 , template: '<span class="checkbox"><input id=wa30_05_#=room_no# name="wa30_05_choice" type="checkbox" value=#=room_no#><label for=wa30_05_#=room_no#></label></span>'},
             { field: "room_no"                 , title: "roomNo"   , width: 50}, 
             { field: "room_type_name"          , title: "roomName"     , width: 40}, 
             { field: "room_status_name"        , title: "roomStatusName"   , width: 50},
             { field: "remark"                  , title: "remark"       , width: 100}
         ]

     });
```

If you press the Save button, I want to bring dataitem to only those that have checked the checkbox in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution:traverse checkbox

```
   ` $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index,elem){
            if(this.checked==true){
                $(this).parent().parent()
        //you can get tr element then get the data you want
        }
        });`
```

The specific solution:read the document of the grid control that you used;There must be some method to help you get the data.